# Old French papers which haven't been translated into English

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, mathematical-french

So I've been studying French for a few years now and I've decided that translating an old French math paper into English would be a good exercise to further improve my French competency.  I would also like to translate a paper that hasn't already been translated so that my work might be useful to someone somewhere.

I was wondering if anyone knows of a good source on the Internet to find old French math papers, something in algebra/algebraic geometry would be preferable and the older and more elementary the better, as I'm certainly no mathematician (yet).

Comment: http://www.numdam.org/ may help you. Bon courage !

Comment: Your work will be very very very useful for me if you decide to translate this article http://math.berkeley.edu/~pavlov/scans/guichardet.pdf. This is just  a proposal :)

Comment: Great site Davide Giraudo I think I might try my hand at one of those from the 1800's, is there anyway to tell if a paper has already been translated other than searching for its english language equivalent on google?                                                              Also @Norbert, the math in your paper is beyond me, but it seems to be mostly exposition and so if your not worried about the translator not understanding the math then I can probably do it.

Comment: Clarification: that is to say the exposition seems quite transparent.

Comment: @Poopsilon I'm sure your translation will be much more better then mine or computer translation.

Comment: @Nobert You'd actually be surprised how good google translate is for languages as similar as english/french, anyways though, it's quite long but I should be able to finish it within a few weeks if that's good for you.  You can send me your email at poopsilon@yahoo.com

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [the Euler Archive](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~euler/), which contains all 800 articles of Leonhard Euler, in his many subjects of interest.

Most of the articles are written in Latin, but some are in French and have not been translated yet. In fact, they are even [looking for translators](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~euler/translations.html)!

Comment: Cool site thanks.  It looks like most of the french has already been mined out, but I did find at least one that appears to still be in need of translation.

Comment: @Klaus: You do know that there's a difference between `f` and `ſ` (long s), right? And the rules for when to use `ſ` vs `s` are quite subtle...